# How to change file names in bulk, beginner here

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, rename

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evB9V.png)

I have files names like that in a directory, what I want to do is,

```
ISOLUX_LL2023_864-EN-P4-500-730.JPG
```

rename this file for example to;
LL2023_864-EN-P4-500-700.jpg

first to delete "ISOLUX_" from all, then turn the file extension to.jpg,

I am a beginner by the way, don't know much about using Python. Thanks in advance

I tried the codes I found online but couldn't manage them to work

Comment: You haven't tagged a language. I assume you mean Python, and probably Python 3. Add the appropriate tags to your question.

Comment: Would you like make this from command line or shell or from programming language? On which type of OS or programming language?

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot I did add the language. Sorry I have never actually used this website. Programming language is not necessarily needed, if it is possible from the command line or shell also I could make it work.

Comment: @tangent The question is _not_ specific to python version 3 so the proper tag is `python`.

Comment: @ack I didn't say it was, and you don't know whether the OP intended to be specific or not. I speculated on a version and left the OP to add the appropriate tags.

Comment: You still didn't state your OS, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Guys thank you all, my OS is Windows and I am using Python 3 right now, that's the one I installed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, As you have not mentioned a way the "bulk" files should be named I just made a list to name them.

The file names would change for the old file name, check the number of files in the folder for the `range(3)`.

You can also use a loop to create a list of the new names.

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

new_file_name = ["10.txt", "20.txt", "30.txt"] # new file names

cwd = os.getcwd()
old_file_name = [os.path.join(cwd, f) for f in os.listdir(cwd) if 
os.path.isfile(os.path.join(cwd, f))] #getting the file names in the folder

for i in range(3): #Changing file name
    os.rename(old_file_name[i], new_file_name[i])
```